# Bootstrap 5 svg icons do not appear

Tags: css, icons, bootstrap-5

I have added a footer from bootstrap official docs examples
but the social icons do not seem to appear .
I have added these cdns :

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <div class="container">
  <footer class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3 my-4 border-top">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
      <a href="/" class="mb-3 me-2 mb-md-0 text-muted text-decoration-none lh-1">
        <svg class="bi" width="30" height="24"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>
      <span class="text-muted">© 2021 Company, Inc</span>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end list-unstyled d-flex">
      <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted" href="#"><svg class="bi" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#twitter"></use></svg></a></li>
      <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted" href="#"><svg class="bi" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#instagram"></use></svg></a></li>
      <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-muted" href="#"><svg class="bi" width="24" height="24"><use xlink:href="#facebook"></use></svg></a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

[image]

and this is the part of the code :
[image]

Comment: You need ad some code in `href`.  <use xlink:href="`boostrap-icons.svg`#twitter"></use> . You can see how it is used [here](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#usage)

Comment: Thx i will read that, but i copied it from the bootstrap site in which they appear .

Comment: You are calling the class class="bi"` but something is missing .  Try adding this class : `class="bi bi-facebook" `

Comment: I used another technique , I have added `@import url('//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css');
`
added icon 
`<i class="bi-facebook" style="font-size: 2rem; color: cornflowerblue;"></i>
` works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the SVG sprite, you need to include the sprite and reference it in the `<use>` xlink href. See the [example](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install) from the documentation:

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill"/>
</svg>
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#toggles"/>
</svg>
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#shop"/>
</svg>
```

The above code assumes that you have the `bootstrap-icons.svg` file at the same location than the HTML file which contains the code. If not, you need to adapt the path in the `href`.

The SVG you can grab here: https://github.com/twbs/icons/blob/main/bootstrap-icons.svg

If you installed Bootstrap Icons via NPM, you can find the file in:

`node_modules/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg`